# npm WARN saveError EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\...\package.json.3542172463' -> 'C:\...\package.json'

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-server-2016, nvm, npm-update

Environment:

```
Node: 8.11.2 (installed from nvm)
npm: 5.6.0
OS: Windows Server 2016
AV: Only Windows Defender but it has been disabled
```

Used command:

```
npm install
npm install grunt
```

When I run the first command (npm install) all modules described in the package.json file are correctly installed.

When I run the second command (npm install grunt) I get an error:

```
npm WARN saveError EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\...\package.json.3542172463' -> 'C:\...\package.json'
removed 762 packages in 16.89s
```

and several hundred modules are removed from my node_module directory.

Does anyone have a clue what can cause such a problem?

I've already tried to disable proxy, clear the npm cache, disable AV (there is only Windows Defender) with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to the latest npm version (v6.2.0) did the trick :)

Because I've used nvm to install Node.js on Windows I had a little problems to update npm, but I found the below script, written by Adrien Pyke (based on @arfaWong's idea) and published on:
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/300#issuecomment-390293097

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

if [%1] == [] (
    echo Pass in the version you would like to install, or "latest" to install the latest npm version.
) else (
    set wanted_version=%1

    if "!wanted_version!" == "latest" (
        for /f %%i in ('npm show npm version') do set wanted_version=%%i
    )

    for /f %%i in ('npm -g -v') do set cur_version=%%i

    if "!cur_version!" == "!wanted_version!" (
        echo Already on npm version !wanted_version!.
    ) else (
        echo Updating to !wanted_version!...

        set node_path=!PROGRAMFILES!\nodejs

        rename "!node_path!\npm" npm2
        rename "!node_path!\npm.cmd" npm2.cmd
        rename "!node_path!\node_modules\npm" npm2
        node "!node_path!\node_modules\npm2\bin\npm-cli.js" i npm@!wanted_version! -g

        for /f %%i in ('npm -g -v') do set new_version=%%i

        echo New version installed is !new_version!

        if "!new_version!" == "!wanted_version!" (
            echo Successfully updated to !wanted_version!. Cleaning up backups...
            del "!node_path!\npm2"
            del "!node_path!\npm2.cmd"
            @RD /S /Q "!node_path!\node_modules\npm2"
            echo Update complete.
        ) else (
            echo Something went wrong. Rolling back.
            if exist "!node_path!\npm" (
                del "!node_path!\npm"
            )
            if exist "!node_path!\npm.cmd" (
                del "!node_path!\npm.cmd"
            )
            if exist "!node_path!\node_modules\npm" (
                @RD /S /Q "!node_path!\node_modules\npm"
            )
            rename "!node_path!\npm2" npm
            rename "!node_path!\npm2.cmd" npm.cmd
            rename "!node_path!\node_modules\npm2" npm
        )
    )
)
```